# CSS div align horizontal in same line

Tags: html, css

Hi I have use CSS to positioning my div box and this is my result:

```
-------
 div  i
 box1 i
-------
        ----------
        i  div   i
        i  box2  i
        ----------
                   -------
                   i  div
                   i  box3
                   -------
```

I'm sorry that I was unable to upload an image becuz my reputation point is just 2 only, Ok let's continue, the result above I get is breaking each div box into new line but I don't want to be like that, the result I want is align the 3 div boxes into same horizontal line like this:

```
------  ---------  ------
     i  i       i  i
     i  i       i  i
------  ---------  ------
```

this is my CSS code, can someone correct my mistake?

```
#divbox1{
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: -25%;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888888;
}
#divbox2{
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888888;
}
#divbox3{
    display: flex;
    height: auto;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 85%;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888888;
}
```

Addition point: I want to show 20% display of the the divbox1 and 3 only that's why im using -% margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `display:flex;` wrong. It needs to be applied to a parent container to work the way you are expecting it to. You'll need to add an extra div encasing the whole thing like this:

```
<div id="group">
  <div id="divbox1"></div>
  <div id="divbox2"></div>
  <div id="divbox3"></div>
</div>
```

After doing that, you will need to remove `display:flex;` from the inner divs. And add it to the grouping div. The resulting CSS should look something like this:

```
#group{
display:flex;
width:100%;
}

#divbox1{
flex:4;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: -25%;
position: relative;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #888888;
}

#divbox2{
flex:6;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
position: relative;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #888888;
}

#divbox3{
flex:4;
margin-top: 5%;
margin-left: 85%;
position: relative;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #888888;
}
```

Adding the `flex:4;` or `flex:6;` to each inner div is basically telling the flexbox what size you want your divs in relation to each other. Then, by default, flexbox will fit them to the width of the screen unless you have things like `min-width` on your divs.

Hope I helped. Cheers.

Comment: Almost see the result but the divbox3 far from away to with the center box, but at least it's lying on the same line

Comment: Try removing margins from all the #divboxes and see if that helps.

Comment: Sir the image inside the div how to align it center cuz after changing the code it stick to the left side

Answer (score 3):

```css
#divbox1{
    float:left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 10%;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888888;
}
#divbox2{
    float:left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888888;
}
#divbox3{
    float:left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #888888;
}
```

```html
<div id='divbox1'></div>
<div id='divbox2'></div>
<div id='divbox3'></div>
```

Don't use

```
display:flex;
```

Instead just go

```
float:left;
```

in each of the boxes. And play around with the widths, you might need to lessen the values a little bit. and get rid of those margins.

Comment: I changed to float:left; and then the divbox1 and divbox2 aligned in the same horizontal line but the divbox3 still stay at below, and each of the div box containing a image positioned in the center of the divbox if I remove the display: flex; the image will be positioned stick to the left side

Comment: it's because they're too wide to be in the same line. you only have upto width 100% to work with.. see the example that I put. press 'run code snippet' if you want an image in the center. just add an image tag inside the divs and go "text-align:center" on each div style.

Answer (score 0):

Is this were you looking for..?

```css
    .container {
      width: 960px; /* define your container width */
    }

    .box {
      width: 30%; /* whatever width */
      height: 200px; /* whatever height */
      background: #ccc;
      margin: 30px 1%;
      float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="box box1">
      <!-- your content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="box box2">
      <!-- your content goes here -->
    </div>
    <div class="box box3">
      <!-- your content goes here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use px for the width and height because I designing a responsive interface design, ya i just used float left but it's only work for the divbox1 and 2 but box3 have no respond at all

Comment: Do you have a container to wrap the divs..? If it is then define your width in percentages. %. Wait I'll show you the update.

Comment: Check now. Your code not working because your box div widths and margins sum greater than 100% percent. You can have maximum sum of 100% by all widths and margins according to your question.